# Write powershell output to file from within batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Trying to write powershell output to file from within batch file.

```
powershell -executionpolicy bypass -command "(get-date).addminutes(1).tostring('HH:mm')|out-file '$env:temp\newtime.txt'"
```

Doesn't work from within batch file, but works fine directly in powershell window (stripping off the [powershell -executionpolicy bypass -command] of course).

I'm thinking I'm missing escape characters or something of the like?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: I had to run like this for it to work on a test system: `powershell -executionpolicy bypass -command "(get-date).addminutes(1).tostring('HH:mm')|out-file '%tmp%\newtime.txt'"`. Sometimes with batch you may have to escape the pipe with a carrot (e.g. `^|`) but it did not expand to PS `$Env:temp` to expand to PS variable value with cmd.

Comment: just try:  **`PowerShell ... | out-file (-join $env:temp + '\newtime.txt')"`**

Comment: Thank you Vomit and LO, both answers worked.

Comment: You are free to close/delete the question if you want, this is likely a duplicate anyway. You are welcome!